How to turn URL into its Title in Bulk using App Script?
I need to export bulk data for real estate. There is an option to replace the URL with its Title, but you have to do it one by one in Google Sheets. I was hoping to see if there is a way I can do it faster using Apps Script.
I tried IMPORTXML, but it has limits.
I have tried this below, but it only gets the host website's name.
function TitleFromURL(input) {
  var regex = /^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:w{3}\.)?([^\.]+)/;
  var match = input.match(regex);
  return match ? match[1] : '';
}

Sample Data:



Column A
Column B




https://www.realtor.ca/real-estate/27633475/720b-waverley-road-dartmouth-dartmouth
For sale: 720B Waverley Road, Dartmouth, Nova Scotia B2X2G4 - 202426370




Convert a URL into its title using the SPLIT function
The website you provided is protected, which prevents web scrapes from accessing its content. This is due to various security measures, such as CAPTCHAs and IP blocking, which are designed to avoid unauthorized data extraction.
One alternative/possible solution that can be provided is to extract the address directly from the link. This extracted address can then be formatted as 720b Waverley Road Dartmouth Dartmouth.
Sample Sheet Data:

Sample Code:
  function titleFromURL(url) {
  const urlModif = url.split('/').pop().replaceAll("-", " ").replace(/\b(\w)/g, f => f.toUpperCase());
  console.log(urlModif);
  return urlModif;
}

After saving the code back to your sheet, then type this in column B:
=titleFromURL(A1)


Sample Output:

Reference:
SPLIT function

The same can be done with a plain vanilla spreadsheet formula without resorting to scripting: =arrayformula(if(len(A1:A), "For sale: " & proper(substitute(regexextract(A1:A, ".+/\w+?-(.+)"), "-", " ")),))

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon).  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. how to accept the answer
